# Compare two columns strings if exist both columns remove those two records

Tags: command-line, text-processing

```
10/27/20 LGVD   LGVD-DLV1 ---(LGVD repated 6th line so do not disply it)
10/26/20 LPKK   LPKK-DLV1
10/28/20 LFLZ   LFLZ-DEV1  ---(LFLZ-DEV1 repeated 8th line so do not disply it)
11/02/20 LFLZ   LFLZ-TLST
11/01/20 LFZV   LFZV-DLV1
10/30/20 LFSM   LGVD          --(LGVD repated 1st line so do not disply it)
10/28/20 MDNO   MDNO-TLST
10/28/20 LFLZ-DEV1  LFIT-TLST -- (LFLZ-DEV1 repated 3rd  line so do not disply it)
10/28/20 LJID   LJID-TLST
```

Desired output

```
10/26/20 LPKK   LPKK-DLV1
11/02/20 LFLZ   LFLZ-TLST
11/01/20 LFZV   LFZV-DLV1
10/28/20 MDNO   MDNO-TLST
10/28/20 LJID   LJID-TLST
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind making two passes over the file,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];b[$3];next} !($3 in a || $2 in b)' file file 
10/26/20 LPKK   LPKK-DLV1
11/02/20 LFLZ   LFLZ-TLST
11/01/20 LFZV   LFZV-DLV1
10/28/20 MDNO   MDNO-TLST
10/28/20 LJID   LJID-TLST
```